# Prism CompositePresentationEvent fires twice

Tags: c#, wpf, prism

In my infrastructure i publish a event

```
  this.eventAggregator.GetEvent<ReportAddedEvent>().Publish(report);
```

the report is a object

In my controller i subscribe to this event

```
  this.eventAggregator.GetEvent<ReportAddedEvent>().Subscribe(this.OnReportAdded);
```

My problem is that the event fires twice. There is no other place in the entire code where the event is published so im certain that the event is not fired somewhere else and i can see it only fires once.

Anyone have a suggestion or have a solution to problem or knows where the problem lies.

Comment: Maybe the code to subscribe to the event is called two times. You should check this

Comment: Saved my day. I will name my first child Jehof. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the problem is that the code

```
this.eventAggregator.GetEvent<ReportAddedEvent>().Subscribe(this.OnReportAdded);
```

to subscribe to the ReportAddedEvent is executed two times.

You should check (by using a debugger and a breakpoint on the line) if it executes more than once.

Comment: It happened to me because I called two times, in different ViewModels, the instance of the ViewModel that I was subscribing to the event. Thanks Jehof!