# Prism EventAggregator subscribe executing twice

Tags: c#, prism

I have a similar issue to this post [Prism CompositePresentationEvent fires twice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9276494/prism-compositepresentationevent-fires-twice)

My issue is that the `Publish` is only firing once but the code in the `Subscribe` is executing twice.

Here is my publish code.

```
EventAggregator.GetEvent<PubSubEvent<HardwareLoaded>>().Publish(new HardwareLoaded() { HardwareOK = _HardwareOK });
```

And the subscribe code.

```
IEventAggregator.GetEvent<PubSubEvent<HardwareLoaded>>().Subscribe(x =>
{
    if (!x.HardwareOK)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("There was an issue loading hardware. See Log");
    }

    LoadingVisibility = Visibility.Collapsed;                
});
```

I put a breakpoint at both the `Publish` and the `Subscribe` and can see that the publish only fires once but the subscribe code fires twice. This is backed up by the message box showing twice.
I have run a search for any other publish code and found none.

Any ideas?

Comment: The lambda passed to `Subscribe` is called once, this we know, but maybe the call to `Subscribe` has been made twice ?

Comment: Where have you declared the Subscribe code? Could it be that it is your code calling it twice?

Comment: @Bijington ah that's a point, so its actually subscribing twice. I will have a check.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Make sure the `Subscribe` method is called only once.

If it is called twice, the same event will trigger the same callback, just as it would if there were completely different handlers reacting to the same event.

Comment: Sorted it, credit to you and Bijington. I was subscribing in the constructor of a viewmodel. The constructor code was actually being called twice.